# Как правильно использовать транзисторы?

Tags: stm32, электроника

Вопрос скорее не по программированию, а по электронике. Я генерирую ШИМ платой STM32, этим ШИМом необходимо крутить электродвигатель напряжением 24V. Т.е каким то образом нужно увеличить напряжение ШИМа с 3V до 24V. Если попробовать делать транзисторами, то при напряжении 3V мало какие открываются полностью. Поэтому необходимо либо использовать два, либо какой-то, еще неведомый мне, метод бутстрепного конденсатора. Если кто-то сталкивался с такими трудностями, расскажите как решали?

Comment: Обычно напряжение изменяют трансформаторами. Но я крайне далек от электроники

Comment: Даже полевики не открываются? ;) Ну еще можете посмотреть оптопары, твердотельные реле и т.д., для развязки линий 3В и 24В.

Comment: @Croessmah разве твердотельное реле может открываться и закрываться с частотой 1 МГц?

Comment: @Denisok Вы не писали про частоту.

Comment: может всё-таки попробуете полевой транзистор? Например, что-то вроде BSP17 или IRFZ44N.

Comment: Или IRFZ44N. Посмотрел даташиты, оба, вроде, открываются при напряжении 2.2, максимум 4 вольта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы или не понимаете как происходит управление нагрузкой посредством ШИМ или я Вас не понял. Если у вас обычный коллекторный двигатель постоянного тока, то берете например вот эту схему (в сети их миллион)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

где VCC - это Ваше максимальное напряжение 24V. Частоту ШИМа выбираете в несколько кГц и меняя скважность импульсов регулируете обороты. Причем здесь 3V или 10 или еще сколько там. У Вас амплитудное значение не меняется - оно всегда 24V и следовательно транзистор будет открываться, а вот среднее напряжение на нагрузке будет меняться в зависимости от ширины импульсов. Но учтите, что оборты двигателя будут меняться в зависимости от нагрузки на валу, поэтому обычно вводится обратная связь в виде таходатчика или датчика Холла. Микроконтроллер измеряет реальные обороты двигателя и производит дорегулирование. Если вы используете данную схему не забудьте сделать развязку между силовым транзистором и микроконтроллером, в виде еще одного транзистора или оптопары.

Comment: Вопрос наверное даже не в регулировании частоты оборотов, а  вообще в приведении в движение двигателя  который должен работать при 24V, а в наличии только 3V.

Answer (score 0):

Если не хватает напряжения для открытия полевого транзистора, можно использовать биполярный транзистор или непосредственно для управления нагрузкой, или для управления полевым транзистором. Можно, например, для управления полевым транзистором сделать делитель напряжения, верхним плечом которого будет резистор, подключенный к напряжению питания нагрузки, а нижним - слаботочный npn транзистор. Резистор выбирается как компромисс между скоростью открытия полевого транзистора и постоянным током через него при открытом биполярном транзисторе. Так как биполярный транзистор управляется током, между ним и выводом контроллера нужен токоограничительный резистор.